# Maximum of $\frac{x-y+1}{2x-y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $x > y \ge 1$ be integer numbers. Is there an ''effective'' upper bound for $\frac{x-y+1}{2x-y}$? I know that always $\frac{x-y+1}{2x-y}<1$. And for $y$ fixed we have $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x-y+1}{2x-y} = \frac{1}{2}$.

I suspect an upper bound is 2/3, or some value "close" to 1/2 (some value bigger than 1/2 indeed)...

Comment: does answer of 2/3 make sense?  Does it answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, thanks! For $x=2$ and $y=1$, the fraction attains this value.  If the value was lower, it would be even better. But this is already within my hypotheses. Maybe with a few more hypotheses, now I'll be able to improve!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we fix $y$ and let $x = y + w$ with $w>0$, then
$$\frac{x-y+1}{2x-y} = \frac{w+1}{y+2w}.$$
This quantity will be largest for $y = 1$.
So, we consider maximum of
$$\frac{w+1}{2w+1},$$
which is decreasing in $w$ with supremum of $1$ (as $w\rightarrow 0$).
The smallest integer for $w$ is $1$.  So max is
$$\frac{1+1}{2+1} = 2/3.$$